# Save with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I try to simply save a new User in my mongodb base into a controller file :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var UserModel = mongoose.model('User');

// signup
exports.create = function (req, res) {

    console.log(req.body);

    var user = new UserModel({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password,
        email: req.body.email
    });

    user.save(function (err) {
        if (!err) {
            return console.log("created");
        }
        else {
            return console.log(err);
        }
    });
}
```

In debug mode, I can see that user.save() is not executed without error...

I don't know why because I get correct value in username / password / email field.

Here my model file :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var objectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    email: String
});

var userModel = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

EDIT :

In my app.js I have the connection to mongodb :

```
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb', function(err){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });

    var  userModel = require('./models/user'),
        userController = require('./controllers/users');
```

Comment: Where's your `mongoose.connect()`?

Comment: In my app.js and then I require my model.js and my controller.js

Comment: Okay, so what error are you getting exactly?

Comment: No error... Just not enter into the user.save()

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood 'not executed without error' :) Sounds like [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156623/mongoose-js-instance-save-callback-not-firing)

Comment: hum.. ok I see ! Thanks a lot but how can I pass from app.js to model.js the 'var connection' ?

Comment: Are you using `mongoose.createConnection()` or `mongoose.connect()` in your app.js? If you're using `.connect()`, judging by the related issue your code should work (but do make sure `.connect` is actually called)

Comment: yes I use .connect() in my app.js : 'var connection = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb');'

Comment: It might be helpful to add the connection info as an edit to the original question.  It's starting to get hard to follow.

Comment: could you check if your mongoose connect returns an error, with `mongoose.connect(connectionString, function(err){console.log(err)})`

Comment: Yes I added connection info on first post. And mongoose.connect(...) don't returns error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I grouped all (controller + model) in one file to test :

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes  = require('./routes')
  , userRoute    = require('./routes/user')
  , http    = require('http')
  , path    = require('path')
  , io      = require('socket.io')
  , mongoose = require('mongoose');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(require('stylus').middleware(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/mydb', function(err){
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Connected to mongo DB")
    }
});

/*var userModel = require('./models/user'),
    tchatMessageModel = require('./models/tchatMessage'),
    userController = require('./controllers/users'),
    tchatMessageController = require('./controllers/tchatMessages');       */

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/signup', userRoute.signup);
app.get('/signin', userRoute.signin);
//app.post('/signup', userController.create);
//app.get('/users', userRoute.list);

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var userSchema = Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    email: String
});
var UserModel = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
app.post('/signup', function (req, res) {

    console.log(req.body);

    var user = new UserModel({
     username: req.body.username,
     password: req.body.password,
     email: req.body.email
     });

    user.save(function (err) {
        if (!err) {
            return console.log("created");
        }
        else {
            return console.log(err);
        }
    });

});

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

And I get the same issue... don't understand. Maybe issue in Express configuration ?

EDIT :

Issue solved with :

app.js

```
mongoose.model("User", require("./models/user").userModel);
```

model.js

```
exports.userModel = userSchema;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use keyword "new", when you are creating a mongoose Schema:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    /*...*/
});
```

Comment: You don't need `new`, as the `Schema` constructor function is written to work the same either way.