# Mongoose model data not saved

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, model, save

I am working on a nodejs project, using mongoose and mongodb, and when handling a profile update logic, I try to post some data to the server including a profile photo upload, I use formidable to handle the file upload and there is no issue, but my other form fields not being saved even there is no any error message, below it's the route code, please help me where goes wrong.

```
 router.post('/api/profileUpdate/:username', function(req, res, next) {
  User.findOne({
    username: req.params.username
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);

        } else {
            if (user) {
                console.log('user found, going to update ...');
                user.age = req.body.age;
                user.gender = req.body.gender;
                user.description  = req.body.description;
                user.occupation = req.body.occupation;

                var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
                form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
                    //res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
                    //res.write('received upload:\n\n');
                    res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
                });

                form.on('end', function(fields, files) {
                    console.log(fields);
                    console.log(req.body.age);
                    console.log(files);


                    if (this.openedFiles[0]) {
                        /* Temporary location of our uploaded file */
                        var temp_path = this.openedFiles[0].path;
                        /* The file name of the uploaded file */
                        var file_name = this.openedFiles[0].name;
                        /* Location where we want to copy the uploaded file */
                        var new_location = 'public/images/uploads/';

                        fs.copy(temp_path, new_location + file_name, function(err) {  
                          if (err) {
                            console.error(err);
                          } else {
                            user.profile_photo = '/images/uploads/' + file_name + '?dim=200';
                            console.log(user.profile_photo);
                            console.log("success!")

                            // save the data
                            user.save(function(err) {
                                if (err){
                                    console.log('Error in Saving user: '+err);  
                                    throw err;  
                                }
                                console.log('User update succesful');
                                console.log(user.username);
                                console.log(user.profile_photo);

                             });
                          }
                        });
                    }
                    else {

                    }

                });
                res.redirect(req.url);

            }
        }
 });
});
```

Comment: Does the code show the "success!" message in the console?  Also you have an else condition in the outer if/else block that doesn't do anything.  For now it might help to write a debug msg to console in that branch as well.

Comment: Hi Kip, yes, there is "success!" message shown, it also show the username and file path, and the file got uploaded to the server successfully, just the mongodb data not updated, seems the fields data not captured, but no error shown

Comment: Have you seen this question yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156623/mongoose-js-instance-save-callback-not-firing

Comment: Hmm... I didn't see the mentioned thread before, but my case may not be the same, as I can find the user record, just the update not being fired, could it be related to the asynchornous request by formidable as it seems the post data are lost?

Comment: Interesting idea.  Can you test it by commenting out the entire formidable section and adding code similar to this above the file upload:
user.profile_photo = 'TEST';
user.save(function(err){...}

Comment: Mongoose also has a debug mode.  It might be worth trying if you haven't:
`mongoose.set('debug', true);`

Comment: I followed your instruction and comment out all formidable code and try again, the data still not saved, my guess is wrong, below it's the console output: `GET /api/profile/update/test 304 257.988 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 1.398 ms - -
Updating profile for test@home.com
Mongoose: users.findOne({ username: 'test@home.com' }) { fields: undefined }  
user found, going to update ...
User update succesful
test@home.com
test
POST /api/profileUpdate/test@home.com 200 18.677 ms - 240`

Comment: I enabled the mongoose debug mode, as you can see, there is output like `Mongoose: users.findOne({ username: 'test@home.com' }) { fields: undefined }` why the fields are undefined? does it mean it failed to read the schema info?

Comment: One possibility is if you have any strange characters or spaces in your keys.  See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710043/mongoose-mongodb-result-fields-appear-undefined-in-javascript

Comment: Can you post your User schema?

Comment: Hi Kip, I post it below as an answer as I can't post code here, pls take a look, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this other approach to see if the files and fields are all coming through:

```
var fields=[]
var files = []
form.on('field', function(field, value) {
  fields.push([field, value]);
})
form.on('file', function(field, file) {
  console.log(file.name);
  files.push([field, file]);
})
form.on('end', function() {
  console.log('done');
  console.log(files)
  console.log(fields)
});
```

Comment: Hi Kip, I tried your approach, and below it's the output:   `POST /api/profileUpdate/test@home.com 200 43.379 ms - 240
IMG_5973.JPG
done
undefined
undefined
`

Comment: sorry the format is not good for view, i put it as answer below

Comment: I'm not sure why files and fields would be undefined at the end.  At the very least they should print an empty array.  In the `form.on('field'...` section, add `console.log(field); console.log(value); console.log(fields);`

Comment: Hmm I tried to print but seems no luck... in the end I use alternative method multer package and finally get the whole function working, thanks a lot for your help, Kip.