# mongoDB / NodeJS save() method not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm a beginner at NodeJS / MongoDB so maybe it would be easy for you.

I have this simple code :

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird')

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/db_ldap_users", function(err, db) {
    if(err) {
       throw err;
    }
    console.log("connected to the mongoDB !");
});

var usersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({uid : String });

var Users = mongoose.model('Users', usersSchema);

app.get("/test", function(req, res) {
    console.log("Service /test called");
    var users = new Users();
    users.uid = "James";
    console.log("User created");

    users.save(function(err) {
        console.log("Callback");
        if (err) { 
            console.log("error");
            throw err; 
        }
        console.log('added !');
        res.send("ok");
    });
});
```

Here is the output :

```
connected to the mongoDB !
Service /test called
User created
```

The problem is the user is never add to the DB. I have never entered in the callback, I don't know why, I have followed multiple tutorial and it seems to always works for them. Does someone has an idea ?

**EDIT** : I forget to add
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/db_ldap_users");
I was thinking the connection to the Database was enough **Thanks**

Thanks you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongoose save fails without error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20304855/mongoose-save-fails-without-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look this:

```
     var mongoose = require('mongoose');


        mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/db_ldap_users");

       var usersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({uid : String });

       var Users = mongoose.model('Users', usersSchema);

        app.get("/test", function(req, res) {
            console.log("Service /test called");
           var users = new Users();
          users.uid = "James";
          console.log("User created");

         users.save(function(err) {
             console.log("Callback");
                  if (err) {
                   console.log("error");
                  throw err;
         }
            console.log('added !');
         res.send("ok");
        });
   });
```

Comment: can you please add more explanation on this, so that user can understand it more properly?

Comment: Ok this is working the mistake was I didn't do mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/db_ldap_users"); Thanks you !