# Why am I getting error "Trying to open unclosed connection."?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, node-mongodb-native

I am trying to connect my node app to mongodb via mongoose. It seems to be working, as I can add documents, but I get the error `{ [Error: Trying to open unclosed connection.] state: 2 }`.

I created a very simple app, just to make sure everything is working properly before connecting my actual app.

Here is my simple app:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var timeSchema = new Schema({ timestamp: String });
var Time = mongoose.model('Time', timeSchema);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb');

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error: '));
db.once('open', function () {

  var testA = new Test({ timestamp: Date() });

});
```

I also tried adding `db.close()` to the end, but it made no difference.

This is running on a Ubuntu 14.04 VPS with:

- Node.js v0.10.3
- MongoDB 2.6.3
- Mongoose 1.4.21

Answer (score 61, accepted):

In my opinion, you are trying to create another connection without closing the current one. So, you might want to use:

[createConnection()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-createConnection) instead of `connect()`.

In your case, it would look like this:

```
db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/mydb');
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. The real issue was indeed that I was trying to create another connection. I had a second script that I didn't think was being called.

Comment: **Important:** Make sure to construct models from your connection, not from the 'global' mongoose variable directly, or nothing will get saved. In this example you need to create models with `db.model()` instead of `mongoose.model`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10200999/3714913 for a good explanation.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and found that I had the below connection in another file, which was the reason why I couldn't connect with a different database name. The below `createConnection` is needed:

```
db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/mydb');
```

What I had in another file:

```
db = mongoose.Connection('mongodb://localhost/mydb');
```

Answer (score 2):

just use `mongoose.connect('...');` **once**.

maybe in your root **app.js** or **index.js** file, not in every model or database related files if your are importing (including) them.

Anyways, if you still have doubt you can check it by:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.once('connected', function() {
  console.log('mongoDB is connected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't your

```
db.once('open', function () {

  var testA = new Test({ timestamp: Date() });

});
```

be

```
db.once('open', function () {

  var testA = new Time({ timestamp: Date() });

});
```

If "Test" is a different schema based on a different connection, that might affect i think

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but it was due to a typo:

`express-sessions` instead of `express-session`

Comment: @Buddy thanks for the edit, I should have used the snippet