# how to read a json file and save entries to mongodb

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am parsing a JSON file that is an array of objects. I am trying to parse this array with some logic and then save each entry to mongodb via mongoose.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var Show = require('../server/models/show');

Promise.promisifyAll(fs);

// read file
fs.readFileAsync('upcoming-shows.json', 'utf8')
.then(function (resolve, reject) {
    var shows = JSON.parse(resolve);

    shows.forEach(function(show){
        // first entries have no date
        if(typeof show.date != 'undefined'){
            var formatDate = show.date.split('\n')[1].trim();   // Thu 08 Oct 2015
            show.date = formatDate;

            var newShow = new Show(show);
            newShow.headline = show.headline;
            newShow.eventLink = show.eventLink;
            newShow.eventImage = show.eventImage;
            newShow.venue = show.venue;
            newShow.dateString = show.date;

            // console.log(newShow);
            newShow.save(function(err, s){
                console.log(s);

            });

        }

    });

});
```

The `newShow` object looks like a mongodb object

```
{ dateString: 'Fri 25 Sep 2015',
  headline: 'Gui Boratto',
  eventLink: 'http://www.songkick.com/concerts/24627124-gui-boratto-at-mighty',
  eventImage: 'http://images.sk-static.com/images/media/profile_images/artists/404729/large_avatar',
  date: Fri Sep 25 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT),
  venue: 'Mighty',
  _id: 55d7c0e461ed8df612ad232b,
  artists: [] }
```

My mongoose model looks like:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// show model schema
var showSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    artists: [{ type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Artist' }],
    venueId: { type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Venue' },
    date: { type: Date },
    ticketUrl: { type: String },

    headline: { type: String },
    eventLink: { type: String },
    eventImage: { type: String },
    venue: { type: String },
    dateString: { type: String }

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Show', showSchema);
```

However the entry does not save to mongodb! Why isn't the data being added to the database?

Comment: I suggest you double check your model, maybe even post it here. If the object is being output correctly just before the call to save, then the problem isn't in this code.

Comment: @Nocturno yep, I think you're right, the problem may happen in his model.js

Comment: In the save callback function you're ignoring the `err` variable. I would suggest checking to see if an error is being returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay thank you for the replies. The problem occurred because I was trying to add to the collection on a separate connection. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10200999/2031033) helped me.

I dropped in all my connection info before reading the file:

```
// database connection stuff
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
    envConfig = require('../config/env')[env];
mongoose.connect(envConfig.db);
```

Then ran the file itself once with node to add to database

Comment: Damn I almost had it figured out and I was heading down that route. lol nice spot. That should work!