# Blocking Node in Script

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I'm using Node.js to write system scripts that run on a server. Due to Node's asynchronous nature, my script is exiting before the database calls have a chance to complete and nothing is ever written to the database.

I'm using Mongoose as an ORM and talking to a MongoDB, if that makes any difference. Node.js offers SYNCHRONOUS method calls for this very reason, for example: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

I guess my questions are:

1) Does mongoose offer a way to block so my scripting process can wait for the database call to return?

2) If not, is there another method I should consider other than something like:

```
(function wait () {
   if (!SOME_EXIT_CONDITION) setTimeout(wait, 1000);
})();
```

3) Is node not the best tool for the job for writing scripts? I love node for web app development, and can write nested callbacks or work with promises all day long. But what about as a scripting language?

EDIT -----------------------------------------------

Below is an quick example of the script to provide more clarity of the situation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
# Please note the above that this is a bash script

var schema = mongoose.Schema({
   // ... attributes ...
});
var model = new (mongoose.model('ModelObject'))();

model['attribute'] = 42;

console.log('This gets printed first');
model.save(function(err) {
  console.log('Nothing in the callback gets printed because callback is never called');
  if(err) { // Can't check for errors because this is never reached
    console.log('This never gets printed to the screen');
    console.log('And consequently nothing is ever saved to mongo');
  } else {
    console.log('This never gets printed either');
  }
});
console.log('This gets printed second');
```

Comment: It isn't clear what your problem is. "my script is exiting before the database calls have a chance to complete" Can you elaborate on this more? Share your code which produces the problem and describe it in detail.

Comment: The method you have described is perfectly fine, what is stopping you using it?

Comment: Maybe the save method is raising and error and you don´t catch/show it

Comment: Where is the database connection??

Comment: The problem may be caused by Mongo connection mishandling. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156623/mongoose-js-instance-save-callback-not-firing

Comment: There's nothing magical that happens when you run your node program "as a script". It's still being run by node via your #! line, so it's still asynchronous and you need to use callbacks and promises just like you would any node program that used Mongoose.

Answer (score 1):

If your model does not get saved, there is a Mongo error. Following MongoDB conventions you have to check for errors:

```
model.save(function(error, savedItem) {
  if(error) {
    // nothing is saved
  }
});
```

Otherwise, have you considered using Promises? It useful for chaining events and simpler error handling.

```
Promise = require('bluebird');
Promise.promisifyAll(mongoose.Query.base);

model.saveAsync().then(function(savedItem) {
  // saved
})
.catch(function(error) {
  // handle error
});
```

Comment: thank you for your response... however due to the callback never being executed I can't check for errors. The script stops before the callback is ever called. I made edits to hopefully demonstrate a little better the situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this, check below if this help you.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    model1 = mongoose.model('model1'),
    model2 = mongoose.model('model2');

model1.findOne({"type" : 'Active'}, function err(err, catConfig) {
    if(!err.error){
        //This will execute once above DB call is done!
        model2.findOne(condition).remove(function(err, gAnalysis) {
                //Lines of code that you want to execute after second DB call 
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your response. It seems this would work when running node as a web app via node command, but when running as a script the inner call would never be executed because the system exits the script before the callback has a chance to be called. Therefore the function "model2.findOne(condition)" is never called.

Comment: @ossys: The way node works is that the system never exits as long as there are callbacks not yet called.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you opening a connection to the database so presumably saving a model instance does nothing, not even call the callback with an error...

I've tested the below example:

**test.js**:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var kittySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
});

var Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  var silence = new Kitten({ name: 'Silence' });
  silence.save(function (err, saved) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log('Kitty Silence is saved!');

    mongoose.disconnect(function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;

      console.log('done...');
    });
  });
});
```

Running `node test.js` prints this to the console:

```
Kitty Silence is saved!
done...
```

and examining my local test database shows that *Silence* is indeed saved.